# encrypt and decrypt application keys

Tags: java, android, encryption, oauth, proguard

I have lots of keys for various authentication methods that my android app uses. They are currently hardcoded and I simply pass the key to the servers when necessary.

I would like to store them as encrypted, and decrypt them when necessary. Ideally when someone decompiles my application they can't see what my keys are, or if they can see some strings then it will just be an encrypted key that hasn't gone through my decryption function.

I am looking for the best practice for dealing with this problem.

There should have to be an encryption method and decryption method that provides enough entropy that people wouldn't just look at my encrypted key and guess that I encrypted it with base64 or other known method.

insight appreciated

Comment: hi. I just would like to point to a previews similar question with my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457794/securely-storing-credentials/21458465#21458465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for the best practice for dealing with this problem.

If the API you are trying to use offers transient tokens (e.g., AWS's Token Vending Machine), use it, so that you do not bake long-lived keys into the app in the first place. Or, as hexafraction suggest, cook up your own scheme for this, where the API keys are on your server, and your app uses your server to perform operations on the app's behalf.

If the API you are using has a way to tie your use of the API to the signing key of your app (e.g., Play Services), your API key cannot be used without your signing key, and so the fact that it can be found is a non-issue.

You're welcome to spring for [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), which will encrypt data in your app. This does not stop a determined hacker, but it does at least slow one down. Casual hackers may well just bypass your app and go with weaker prey.

And if none of those are an option, don't worry about it. For example, if you are solo developer, and stolen API keys are in your top 100 concerns, you are worrying far too much. Just plan to rotate the keys periodically (e.g., every app update), eventually retiring older keys when they are no longer being used, to minimize the risk of damage if some attacker does get your keys. You have bigger fish to fry, like how you are going to market the app.

In particular, rolling your own crypto, instead of just buying DexGuard, is a waste of time. If you cannot afford the DexGuard license fee, you can't afford to be fussing around rolling your own crypto either. And the odds are modest that your own crypto will be worth the time it took to write it, in terms of defending your keys.

Comment: thanks, this is a venture backed project and DexGuard looks like what I'll need

Comment: @CQM: Oh, absolutely. Though, it might mean one less Aeron chair for the office... :-) In all seriousness, I specifically asked about DexGuard with one Android security researcher whose work I respect. His response was not exactly family-friendly, but he indicated that it wouldn't stop him, but it what might have taken minutes now would take a day-plus. I would still consider rotating the keys, though, if the Web API allows you to have multiple keys that you can rotate that way, just for damage mitigation in case somebody *does* spend the day-plus to get your keys.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to have much luck deterring more than a casual attacker. Not to mention that anyone can determine what your code does and how the keys are encrypted, a tool such as a packet sniffer can easily render your keys useless.

I would recommend shifting trust so that you do not need to authenticate android clients (beyond, perhaps, a username and password owned by the user). If you can tell us exactly what you are trying to secure, then I can edit this answer to provide more detailed ideas on how to secure it securely.

Comment: I use SSL..... that would make a packet sniffer useless, and the keys are not sent in the url part of http requests.  Lets say something like my Twitter Oauth Keys "consumer key and consumer secret" are currently hardcoded in the app, I don't want them to be, but I still need to use them